# How can I use same property with conditional validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm new to MVC and working on a sample application.

Which has user registration and a login form.

In the user registration I need to check the password against a regex to make sure it follows the password policy, so I put following validation on the `Password` property inside the `User` Model:

```
[RegularExpression("(?=.{8,})(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*", ErrorMessage = "Password requirement not met, please check password policy.")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

When I use this property from the Login page the validation is appearing as I defined it in the model but I don't want to check this validation when I call it from the Login page.

Please advise how can I use this property, `Password`, from both the Login and the Registration pages.

Thanks.

Comment: Use different view models. A registration model will need different properties than a login model, such as a ComparePassword property

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the ModelBinder specifically to ignore errors:

```
if (ModelState["Password "] != null) ModelState["Password "].Errors.Clear();
```

You would do this inside your controller.

On the other hand, if you really need it to behave differently in two pages, I'd advice to use two different ViewModels. It's a little bit of code duplication but it's far better than having shared code which is not really the same (and is only similar in terms of naming)

Comment: thanks, If I got toput if conditional to tell ModelBinder where should I put it in?

Comment: Edited answer: in the controller

Comment: I've added in the controller but the validation message still appearing at Login page,

Comment: If you have client-side validation it will still show up in the UI. There's nothing you can do about that, apart from creating different ViewModels. (Or you could meddle with the client side validation, but that's just not a good idea)

Comment: i think I will create a different ViewModel, thanks.